# Can a magnet lose its energy?

Tags: electromagnetism

Can a magnet (or a current-carrying conductor) lose its magnetic energy through moving electrons? How does the energy conversion happen?

Comment: A magnet sets up a magnetic field because there is some alignment of the magnetic domains inside it, be it coming from spins or from some form of orbiting of charged particles inside it. When the magnetic field is used to do something to something else, that something else also sends back an electromagnetic wave at the magnet. The magnetic domains are slightly perturbed, and the net interaction is to weaken the alignment. The magnet then gets weaker as you extract the magnetic energy out of it to do stuff.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Perfect, so if we have a permanent magnet, and we add single electrons into the field that get moved around, over time it will lose it's magnetation?

Comment: This might help. It explains how ferromagnets work - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM). The typical way a permanent magnet becomes demagnetized involve alignment of its domains.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Perhaps make your comment an answer.  In general answering in comments is not the right way to do things on SE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A permanent magnet is an array of atomic magnetic dipoles. If you want to imagine a big brick made of an outrageously huge number of tiny disk magnets, it's a pretty good analogy.

It would take a lot of energy (compared to how many of them there are) to turn one of those atomic dipoles around out of alignment, and it would naturally flip back around and give you energy if you left it alone. We can represent this as a negative-signed potential energy associated with a mathematical object that represents the amount of energy and also the "shape" of how a test charge would exchange the energy associated with its configuration for other kinds of energy as it moved through space. This mathematical object is the *magnetic field*.

---

I'm not certain that the following description associating the magnetic field energy with the configuration of atomic dipoles is 100% correct. Please take with extra skepticism and I'll be happy to correct them if somebody points out an error.

---

The analogy breaks down somewhat when we ask the magnet to do work, because unlike tiny disk magnets (which are themselves made out of atomic magnetic dipoles in real life) the atomic magnetic dipoles can't gain or lose energy except in (relatively) large, quantized jumps between quantum mechanical energy levels, but the configuration of many dipoles can gain or lose energy continuously by changing its shape. We can pretend that the disk magnets are magic disk magnets that have that rule imposed on them: the only way for the imaginary big block made out of tiny magic disk magnets to do work is for one or more of the tiny disk magnets to turn out of alignment.

When we take energy out of the magnetic field associated with a permanent magnet (that is: we make the potential energy more negative in order to make some other energy-holding mathematical object less negative (like lifting a weight towards the magnet against gravity) or more positive (like increasing the kinetic energy of a projectile deflecting towards the magnet), some of those tiny magic disk magnets are being tipped a little bit out of alignment.

However, the amount of energy associated with the alignment is very large, and we don't actually have any way of taking it out of the system. The magnet can't lose magnetization by repeatedly magnetically attracting the same piece of iron. When the piece of iron is close, the potential energy associated with its position relative to the magnet is more negative, and the potential energy associated with the magnet's internal configuration is less negative. When we pull the iron away, the potential energy associated with its position relative to the magnet is less negative, and the potential energy associated with the magnet's internal configuration becomes more negative as the dipoles naturally line back up again.

We **can** make the total magnetization of the permanent get less, however - just not by moving iron around in the magnetic field. There are many low-energy configurations that don't have the magnets all lined up. There's no path from one low-energy configuration to another that doesn't involve a higher-energy configuration in between. With the brick of tiny disk magnets, we could break the brick of magnets up into chunks and line them up so that instead of being all north to south, the chunks (each still composed of many tiny disk magnets) are mostly at right angles to each other. We'd have to push and pull and pry and press to make it happen, but we'd get lots of painfully pinched fingers and a warmed-up brick as the magnets snapped into energetically into their new configurations. Or we could save time by putting our brick in a sturdy box and shaking it violently; it'll end up in a random low-energy configuration on its own.

Some low-energy configurations actually have a little bit less energy (more negative) than the perfectly lined up configuration of our original big brick, so if you did this and did the same to a similar box full of unmagnetized iron, you'd find that the magnet box was just a tiny bit warmer than the unmagnetized iron box afterwards.

Going back to the atomic scale, we can skip the box and use heat to induce lots of violent motion on the atomic scale. For instance, we could take a neodymium magnet and use tongs to hold it in a candle flame for a minute while wearing safety glasses.

All the magnetic potential energy associated with the magnetic field (configuration of the atomic magnetic dipoles) is still there when you're done, but the shape of the magnetic field has changed drastically: the change in potential energy associated with a given change in configuration is only large within the permanent magnet itself. We can describe this as having field lines that do not extend far beyond the surface of the magnet. Such a magnet no longer does much work on nearby pieces of iron and is *demagnetized*.

Comment: If we take a look at the hysteresis curve, we have to apply a negative magnetic field strength for the magnet to lose it's influence on other magnetic dipols? Or does there actually happen a reduce of potential energy?